# How to expose fastapi/docs to the internet using ngrok?

Tags: deployment, fastapi, ngrok

I have currently built up a FastAPI app(Uses uvicorn to start a local server) hosting a Machine Learning Model on a remote server.
VSCode currently can port forward to the computer I'm running and thus the API docs can be opened on it by opening "intended_ip:port/docs"

I would like to expose the said docs(API testing tab) to the Internet

I have managed to expose the port using ngrok but am not able to expose the SwaggerUI testing panel , I know very little about networks and port forwarding and thus the problem is a challenge to me.

Comment: PM from ngrok here. Can you share the ngrok commands you have tried? Also, ngrok can forward to any number of ports with the same agent using the config file.  You can see an example in the [ngrok agent config docs](https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels/ngrok-agent/reference/config/#tunnel-definitions). You can edit your config file using `ngrok config edit` to add these definitions.